# facebook debugger curl error: operation_timeouted

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I paste my link on facebook debugger, it started to scrape my page, after a few seconds,

it showed the following message

**Curl Error** 
`OPERATION_TIMEOUT Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 56153 out of 121251 bytes received`

and each time trying , the millisecond and received bytes are different.

There are my links
http://www.hkgolden.com/articles/article.aspx?id=16639&catid=19
http://www.hkgolden.com/articles/article.aspx?id=16631&catid=26

I followed the guide line from Facebook to create the og tag, and I am using APSX/C# to create my page, is there any idea to fix this? many thanks